# how to get buffer from AVAudioEngine's installTap at high frequency

Tags: swift, avaudioengine

I am looking to render audio waveform on screen like iOS voice memo app, so I am using AVAudioEngine and installed Tap on input node. But it gives fastest call back on 0.1sec frequency , I need to get buffer data on faster frequency , so that can draw more and more waveform on screen for smooth and realtime visualisation.

Could you please sugger better approach for it ?

```
    let inputNode = self.audioEngine!.inputNode
    let format = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
    
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 4096, format: format) { [self] (buffer, time) in
        processAudioData(buffer: buffer)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            audioPlotView.setNeedsDisplay(). // Render waveform on screen
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how to handle this. Instead of getting very small amounts of new data at a high frequency, you should factor your code to get a larger chunk of data on a longer time interval.

You can then set up your display code to start an animation to animate in a graph of the new data over the time interval you are given. 1/10th of a second is actually a pretty short time interval for an animation.

I would suggest averaging the amplitude of the data for that 1/10th of a second time interval and animating that new average data into place.

BTW, see the [update I posted to the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67660646/205185) about creating an animated graph of the data.

The animation I came up with looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ducan for your code it is really helpful to build understanding ...
Here we need to scroll back & forth over waveform as well, so I did bit more research and found that UIScrollView helps for it.
So now I render lines on content view's layer and change content view frame to shift it back & increate content view width, and change scrollview contentsize & contentoffset accordingly 

please let me know your opinion. following is link to watch demo output video.

https://github.com/singham2012/audio/blob/main/README.md